# Duplicate declaration of method 'application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:'

Tags: swift, firebase, react-native, push-notification

I am working on "react-native-firebase": "^5.5.6", and "react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.9", using react native and I am stuck with error Duplicate declaration of method 'application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:' on appDelegate.m

I have tried various solutions found over web and If I comment one of the method, I got error "native module cannot be null"

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings 
*)notificationSettings {

  [[RNFirebaseMessaging instance] 
 didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}

// Required to register for notifications
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings 
*)notificationSettings
{
[RCTPushNotificationManager 
didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}
```

I need both the methods in my code without any error. I can use if else or other solutions as well but as I am new to this technology, therefore any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend mixing features however try this:

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings 
    *)notificationSettings {

      [[RNFirebaseMessaging instance] 
     didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];

[RCTPushNotificationManager 
    didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];

    }
```

So you initialize both, in the same method. Again, not sure why you need both and you should try to keep only one.